# I want my borders of my divs to overlap completely, but get weird staggering when I align them with flex

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

A big beginner here, but I am trying to align my `div`s in rows so that the border design doesn't get overly thick where they touch.

For some reason I can't use the *pre* to write the html so I will write it in plain text.

```css
.site {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.box1 {
  background: #000000;
  background: #000000;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.box2 {
  background: #000000;
  background: #000000;
  background: #000000;
  margin: -3px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 730px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <div class="box1">Box 1</div>

  <div class="box2">Box 2</div>

</div>
```

I haven't gotten to that point yet, but I also want the entire `.site` to have a 3 px black border around it. I basically want a `.site` with a 3 px black border, and 3 px dividers between the different components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a small code for you. You can choose any one out of the two snippets.

Case 1: 3px border for your .site class, as well as neat and clean div to differentiate between the .site class and the two divs within.

```css
.site, .box1, .box2{
display: flex;
padding:7px;
border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <div class="box1">Box 1</div>

  <div class="box2">Box 2</div>

</div>
```

Case 2: Slightly border change, but as per your need, 3px border for your .site class will remain same in this case as well.

```css
.site{
display:flex;
border:3px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}

.box1, .box2{
border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <div class="box1">Box 1</div>

  <div class="box2">Box 2</div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try below CSS for box2:

```
.box2{
    background: #000000;
    background: #000000;
    background: #000000;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 730px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the entire site to have a border, you can give your `<body>` a border. 
For your elements, have you tried giving the relevant sides a border of just 1.5px?

Comment: "entire site" doesn't mean the `body`, it means the wrapper with class name `.site`